# Is it possible to return a custom error for a logon trigger?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, trigger, raiserror

I'm trying to get a logon trigger to return a custom error.  Thus far everything I have tried causes it to return the standard error:

[image]

My trigger looks like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Test_Logon_Trigger
ON ALL SERVER 
FOR LOGON
AS
BEGIN

IF ORIGINAL_LOGIN()= 'login_test' 
    BEGIN
        raiserror('Custom Error',25,16) 
        --PRINT 'Print'
        --ROLLBACK;
    END
END;
```

I have tried printing an error message and using a RAISERROR command separately and in combination.  I've also tried using the WITH NOWAIT clause on RAISERROR.  In all cases it just sends the message to the error log.  Does anyone know how to modify the error being returned displayed on the screen?  I'm even ok with returning a second error if necessary.

Comment: Do you still want the login to succeed, or are you trying to prevent certain logins from logging in even though they can log in successfully? And you just want to display a custom message so that they don't see that their log in was caught in a trigger?

Comment: Specifically I was thinking the trigger would prevent the user from logging in but return the reason why to them.  For example if I want to restrict users from using a sql login from any application other than the specific application it was created for I want it to return the error: "You are not allowed to use this login." If however they are using the wrong workstation I want it to say "You are not allowed to log in from this workstation."

Comment: Gotcha. I don't believe there's any way to influence or override what is displayed in that SSMS UI.

Comment: How about the other way?  Is there a way to print something on the screen after they have logged in?  In say a query window?

Comment: Don't think so - the logon trigger has no idea about the query window context (if it does exist). This is similar to trying to raise a msgbox or similar - the processes are more detached than you think.

Comment: Oh well.  Thanks.  If you want to move the comments into an answer I'll mark it.

Comment: I'm hoping someone has some clever hack I haven't thought of...

Comment: Why do you think I put the question in in the first place :)

Comment: I thought maybe causing an error in Resource Governor's classifier function might pre-empt the logon trigger error, but all it does is log an error in the error log, and prevent classification from happening (and I only fully tested that after dropping the logon trigger).

Answer (score 3):

This behaviour is a security feature to make hacking more difficult, specifically *because* there is no variation in the output depending on the input. (Aside from exposing the fact there is a logon trigger active.)

If a password is mistyped, the system doesn't respond with an error saying "the password is wrong" or even whether the login name specified exists. If it told you why, this makes penetrating the system much easier because there's less guesswork involved.

So really if there is a way to do this using built-ins, I would have no hesitation to report it as a bug.

That of course doesn't solve what you're trying to do, which, IMO, is questionable for the same reasons.

Since login failures should be rare, what I would suggest is that all the restrictions be published internally in a predictable location (e.g., SharePoint). The main things with this are to make sure the list stays up-to-date (it could be data-driven), and also that it's visible to everyone who has access to the server (as opposed to everyone who is able to *attempt* to connect to the server, which is very different).